# Convert PDF String to Base64 and then download PDF in React JS

Tags: reactjs

Aim : I have a PDF Document in Blob , I Converted the document into Pdf String and then to base64 format respectively. I am trying to download it as a PDF document once i click download button. Note - I am getting this PDF string from Blob (I am passing this string from Server to Client Side)

Code to convert PDF to Buffer -

```
const streamToBuffer = async (readableStream: any) => {return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const chunks: any[] = [];
readableStream.on('data', (data: any) => {
  chunks.push(data instanceof Buffer ? data : Buffer.from(data));
});
readableStream.on('end', () => {
  resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
});
readableStream.on('error', reject);});};
```

using the below code to convert the PDF File from blob to PDF String and then to base64 -

```
    const downloadBlobToString = async (containerClient: any, blobName: any) => {
  const blobClient = await containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
  const downloadResponse = await blobClient.download(0);
  const downloaded = await streamToBuffer(downloadResponse.readableStreamBody);
  const encodedString = Buffer.from(downloaded.toString()).toString('base64');
  return encodedString;
  
};
```

Problem Statement - The file is getting downloaded but getting error as "Failed to load document" once i try to open it.

PDF String -

```
%PDF-1.7 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R ] /Count 1 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R /Font << /F1 8 0 R /F2 9 0 R >> >> /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000] >> endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text ] endobj 5 0 obj << /Producer (��dompdf 1.0.2 + CPDF) /CreationDate (D:20221216202946+00'00') /ModDate (D:20221216202946+00'00') /Title (��Untitled Spreadsheet) /Author (��Unknown Creator) >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000] /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 822 >> stream x����N�@��y��zil��mn�Ҫ��P��—��:����Q; ;�j{�-��&3��;�<QBJ ���zb�0���Z��V���װ��b"w����>b�r�N����M�oQ�J4��%�R-�w�Y!���j���>*X#*�����8��x�J(�`:��4(��������E�z|s �S8�N:)Ф���J4ʼ����U#�Lk��f#ccS���P�g�E�w��];��gp���sY g|��Zho1x��m�7M��+�YGww��28~f���*X|�.��()��)�ǡ��;�҃O�=��t-�N����� V���/�3����j�;�C{a����@�������Dx>���n8��nS����;ٔ9"�%G�Ғ#8m�kCqY � qi�޸J(�+�A�C���+��O-A�%r�� ݵ!� �+x�^���9�<\�^�ۛ�ͪ�tޟ �=�d���;��>�Tً?`��I�ptΨp��GۺH��B��z@���z����a=��6�Ġ�hQw�+���@a��ӦK6�m@qC�$.��W�Mzp�J���P�`��A�hC�UJ(�y�0|����_=��_m[�>�#���r��E��=T���!v�J �������`���v�:}s�Bo��絨R�P!�z�Q)�g��8�w��~�PΔ)%@��H�z52&n�p"�0'*p�}��]d�8��.����g�q'���=v��J���࿽��j�3Y.�,����Qgn=�xq?���߁I'U �GD�����݀�� endstream endobj 8 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F1 /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj 9 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F2 /BaseFont /Times-Roman /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj 10 0 obj [6 0 R /Fit] endobj xref 0 11 0000000000 65535 f 0000000009 00000 n 0000000074 00000 n 0000000120 00000 n 0000000284 00000 n 0000000313 00000 n 0000000557 00000 n 0000000660 00000 n 0000001554 00000 n 0000001661 00000 n 0000001770 00000 n trailer << /Size 11 /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R /ID[<73c60b8a58a461322f732d1e85a77dd1><73c60b8a58a461322f732d1e85a77dd1>] >> startxref 1799 %%EOF
```

PDF - Base64 Conversion

```
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
```

Solution Tried -

```
const base64ToArrayBuffer = (base64: any) => {
const binaryString = window.atob(base64);x
const binaryLen = binaryString.length;
const bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
for (let i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
  const ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
  bytes[i] = ascii;
}
return bytes;

const saveByteArray = (reportName: any, byte: any) => {
const blob = new Blob([byte], { type: 'application/pdf' });
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const fileName = reportName;
link.download = fileName;
link.click();
```

Then calling the two above function as below

```
const sampleArr = base64ToArrayBuffer(props.offerLetterPdf);
saveByteArray('DownloadedPDF', sampleArr);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank You,

Comment: Ok , In that case, Can we take any PDF file and convert that to PDF and Base64 , Because i tried multiple files of PDF and i ma getting the same thing. Can you please share me the source code what you are trying to do - Thanks!

Comment: @K J , I used the same sample files - PDF format , But still the same issue , Do you have any sample code where it works for you or any fiddler link where you can show - Thanks!

Comment: @K J , I have tried converting PDF to Buffer and then convert Buffer to Base64 and then use it but i still have the same issue. getBlobClient is an inbuilt to use for Azure Blobs as listed for the below assembly. Also i have added that code used to convert stream to buffer.
Namespace: Azure.Storage.Blobs
Assembly: Azure.Storage.Blobs.dll

Comment: @K J , If you don't mind , Can you please share a fiddler or a piece of code where it is working for you. - Thank You

Comment: @K J - I have looked into all the links online , But it didn't work so had posted this question , For the first link - I have tried mostly all the solutions - Half of them is for File readers where in we provide pdf file and it converts . It would be much appreciated and useful if you can provide a example of PDF where it works for my scenario listed in the question. - Thank You!

Comment: @KJ - This link has the similar code i have implemented for the current scenario. All i can say the file is a valid PDF, I used a valid pdf also tried with the PDF you shared ie colours.pdf , Still i am facing the same issue.